# ¿Cómo conservar el contexto?

Tags: javascript

```
function A() {

  this.nombre = 'Stack Overflow';
  this.age = 14;
  this.community = true;
   mm.bind(this)();


}

var b = new A();

function mm() {

  console.log(this.age * 2);


}


(function execute(){

  mm();

})();
```

Si llamo a la función del constructor `A()` , ***me funciona todo bien***, pero ***como puedo conservar el contexto*** de `A()` *para que pueda ser USADO por* `mm()`, ***aunque esta última ya no sea llamada desde*** `A()`, ***sino desde otras funciones***, como en este caso desde `execute()` ?

**Nota:** he estado leyendo de `apply()` y `call()` ,pero realmente no los he entendido y necesito que alguien me explique una forma clara para alguien que no lo sabe por favor

He intentado esto y funcionó: => Metodo bind()

```
(function execute(){

  var c = mm;

  c.bind(b)();

})();
```

***Pero como sería con apply y call?***

Además intenté esto:

```
(function execute(){
  var c = mm;
  c.call(b)();

})();
```

**y funcionó pero también me dió un error, que raro! alguien podría explicarme todo esto?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que `mm()` utiliza `age` que le pertenece a una instancia de `A` ¿por qué no lo haces parte del prototype de `A`?

```js
function A() {
    this.nombre = 'Stack Overflow';
    this.age = 14;
    this.community = true;
}

A.prototype.mm = function () {
    console.log(this.age * 2);
};


(function execute(){
    var b = new A();
    b.mm();
})();
```

De esta forma encapsulas la lógica de `mm` que le "pertenece" a `A` en un método que puede ser llamado sobre la instancia `b`

> Edit: Si por algún extraño motivo no se desea incluir a `mm` dentro del prototipo de `A` puede asignarse el objeto b a la función `mm` mediante `call`. De todas formas esto **no es recomendable** porque habría que acordarse de pasar siempre el objeto al cual se refiere this en cada llamada a la función.

```js
    function A() {
        this.nombre = 'Stack Overflow';
        this.age = 14;
        this.community = true;
    }

    function mm() {
        console.log(this.age * 2);
    };


    (function execute(){
        var b = new A();
        mm.call(b);
    })();
```

Comment: Porque necesito usar call() y/o apply()

Comment: No necesitas usar `call` o `apply` puedes invocar directamente a mm desde una instancia de `A` si lo haces de esta forma

Comment: Losé Carlos, pero necesito saber como funcionan call y apply

Comment: Hola Eduardo, bueno eso es una pregunta diferente a la que mencionas, de todas maneras edité mi respuesta.

Comment: Muy bien Carlos , por último por favor para no hacer solo una pregunta con este tema, podrías editarla con apply?

Comment: En este caso que la función `mm´ no recibe parámetros `apply` se comporta de la misma manera que `call`

Comment: Gracias Carlos, sino apply recibe argumentos como array, no?